# Excel - Bi-Weekly Tasks - Fill Calendar

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a Task month calendar. when i change the month of the calendar it shows me what I have to do which day of the month.

I basically have a list of task, when i change the month the tasks date automatically change accordingly a series of rules and that list will populate the calendar.

[Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHhwf.jpg)

[Tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUDnS.jpg)

But I have some tasks that are bi-weekly, and I dont have a specific week to be done, they have to be done in the fortnight after the last time.

so I have the first week (day) that the task was done and i have the first day of the month i am... and with that i would wanted to know which days of the month i have to do that specific task.

Can you help me?

Comment: Why re-create functionality that is not only already perfected, but that you already have sitting in front of you, ready-to-use?  (I'm referring, of course, to the calendar & task manager built into Outlook, which you have if you have Excel 2016.)

Comment: Well this is a team calendar (which member as a color) and some tasks aren't always straight forward, they have several rules to determine in each day they should be done. And finally we have some "reporting" based on the time spend on the tasks... so the excel works for us, not as much as outlook would work...

Comment: Outlook is *made* for managing shared team calendars (even assigning each member a different colour) and reporting is easy since Outlook is also made to easily integrate with Excel, Access and dozens of other platforms. I'm not saying that you won't be able to build your own calendar too; but I am saying if you spent the same amount of time learning how to use the [already debugged & tested] features you already have at your disposal, you'd benefit in the long run.  Regardless, I'm unclear on your specific question: you're trying to calculate a due date of one month from now?

Comment: ...(See also ["creating a calendar group"](https://support.office.com/article/create-view-or-delete-a-calendar-group-04fc64f2-b658-450b-8dce-dd27ed660570) and ["setting up a team calendar"](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/715) and ["review complete/incomplete tasks"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-all-tasks-marked-complete-1b411fe4-f45b-4559-816f-e5a9bee87ba0) and ["Outlook's group calendar views"](http://www.outlookipedia.com/outlook/group-calendar.aspx#Outlooks_built-in_Group_Calendar_View_(calendars_shown_side_by_side)).)

Comment: Thanks for the help... the outlook is really an idea... but first i should sell the idea :). But what I want is every time i change a month in my calendar it should calculate which days the task is going to be done... what i know is the first time the task was made, and was made biweekly ever since...

Comment: At the end of the day, the "right way" is "whatever way gets the job done", so if yours works, that's great... I'm just compelled to share existing solutions when possible, because I've seen people waste countless hours in development, only to eventually trash their hard work in favour of an existing solution. In fact, the last question I answered was a similar story. :)  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

use the last reference point as the basis for creating the next due date. this would be the date the task was last performed. If it is due a fortnight from that last date then add 14 days. You may want to record the date that task was performed each time so that your formula is based on the date it was last completed each time it is calculated.

If you are wanting to plan ahead then make an assumption that it will be done in consistent 14 day iterations then build your formula to consider the actual date it was completed to readjust the plan going forward. So it will assume this will be done consistently until advised otherwise with an actual date it was last completed.

Comment: I didnt wanted to save the last date... because supposedly the calendar isnt something stagnated, i can change a month (back or forward) anytime i pleased.... The only thing i know is the first time the task was made... And which month i am, and based on the first time and the month i am, i wanted to see the days of that month the task should be done...

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to get the first date in the month that matches the weekday of the last date and then you can easily add 14 days.  Much like finding the first Monday/Sunday in a month to build a calendar.

A1 contains the last time the task was performed

C1 contains the 1st of the month

```
C1+7-WEEKDAY(C1+7-weekday(A1))
```

will return the next weekday that matches the weekday the task was last performed.

```
=C1+7-WEEKDAY(C1+7-weekday(A1))-A1
```

returns the number of days since

```
=(C1+7-WEEKDAY(C1+7-weekday(A1))-A1)/2
```

returns the number of days divided by 2.  If this result is not a whole number (#.5) then it's not in the bi-weekly cycle and we need to add another 7 days to get the correct start date.  If it is a whole number then it is our start date.  We can use the `mod` function to find out if there is a decimal value.

```
=if(mod((C1+7-WEEKDAY(C1+7-weekday(A1))-A1)/2,1)>0,C1+7-WEEKDAY(C1+7-weekday(A1))+7,C1+7-WEEKDAY(C1+7-weekday(A1)))
```

Below or next to this cell you can simply reference the cell and add 14 `=D1+14` and then add as many as you want to display.

Comment: My problem, now, really is to have the last weekday was performed... i didnt wanted to save it manually...